# How Improve SQLite Performance?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I want to inset more than 3000 records in android SQLite but the following code take to much time for the data inserion
Here is my code.

```
public boolean addSale(Sale objSale) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SALE_BRANCH, objSale.getBranch());
    values.put(SALE_SUPPLIER, objSale.getSupplier());
    values.put(SALE_BUYER, objSale.getBuyer());
    values.put(SALE_CAT1, objSale.getCat1());
    values.put(SALE_CAT2, objSale.getCat2());
    values.put(SALE_CAT3, objSale.getCat3());
    values.put(SALE_CAT4, objSale.getCat4());
    values.put(SALE_CAT5, objSale.getCat5());
    values.put(SALE_CAT6, objSale.getCat6());
    values.put(SALE_DESIGNO, objSale.getDesigNo());
    values.put(SALE_ITEMSIZE, objSale.getItemSize());
    values.put(SALE_SALEQTY, objSale.getSaleQty());
    values.put(SALE_STOCKQTY, objSale.getStockQty());
    values.put(SALE_FinalProduct, objSale.getFinalProduct());
    values.put(SALE_PriceRange, objSale.getPriceRange());
    values.put(SALE_CoreNonCore, objSale.getCoreNonCore());
    values.put(SALE_Color, objSale.getColor());
    values.put(SALE_GSLCode, objSale.getGSLCode());
    values.put(SALE_Wanted, objSale.getWanted());
    values.put(SALE_Pqty, objSale.getPqty());
    values.put(SALE_MRP, objSale.getMRP());
    values.put(SALE_PRate, objSale.getPRate());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    db.insert(TABLE_SALE, null, values);
    db.close();
    return true;
}
```

And this one is my Asynk Task. Where i fetch data from webservice and insert into SQLite

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            try {

                String l = result.replace("\\", "");
                l = l.replace("''", "");
                String sdsd = l.substring(1, l.length() - 1);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sdsd);
                Log.i("JSON", "Number of surveys in feed: " +jsonArray.length());
                /*if(db.delSaleData()){

                }*/
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            sl.setBranch(jsonObject.getString("Branch"));
                            sl.setSupplier(jsonObject.getString("Supplier"));
                            sl.setBuyer(jsonObject.getString("Buyer"));
                            sl.setCat1(jsonObject.getString("Cat1"));
                            sl.setCat2(jsonObject.getString("Cat2"));
                            sl.setCat3(jsonObject.getString("Cat3"));
                            sl.setCat4(jsonObject.getString("Cat4"));
                            sl.setCat5(jsonObject.getString("Cat5"));
                            sl.setCat6(jsonObject.getString("Cat6"));
                            sl.setDesigNo(jsonObject.getString("DesigNo"));
                            sl.setItemSize(jsonObject.getString("ItemSize"));
                            sl.setSaleQty(jsonObject.getString("SaleQty"));
                            sl.setStockQty(jsonObject.getString("StockQty"));
                            sl.setFinalProduct(jsonObject.getString("FinalProduct"));
                            sl.setPriceRange(jsonObject.getString("PriceRange"));
                            sl.setCoreNonCore(jsonObject.getString("CoreNonCore"));
                            sl.setColor(jsonObject.getString("Color"));
                            sl.setGSLCode(jsonObject.getString("GSLCode"));
                            sl.setWanted(jsonObject.getString("Wanted"));
                            sl.setPqty(jsonObject.getString("Pqty"));
                            sl.setMRP(jsonObject.getString("MRP"));
                            sl.setPRate(jsonObject.getString("PRate"));

                            if(db.addSale(sl))
                            {
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Insert.." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                            }
                    }

                    setData();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            setTableData("All");


        }
```

Comment: Check this .. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/turbocharge-your-sqlite-inserts-on-android/

Comment: Do you do this only once when the app is first started?

Comment: Is this any wrong in this que..?if not then why voted negative?

Answer (score 2):

use the SQLiteStatement for example:

```
private void bulkInsertRecords(String[] records) {
          String sql = "INSERT INTO "+ SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +" VALUES (?,?,?);";
          SQLiteStatement statement = sampleDB.compileStatement(sql); //Este é o prepare
          sampleDB.beginTransaction();
          for (int i = 0; i<records.length; i++) {
                    statement.clearBindings();
                    statement.bindString(1, records[0]);
                    statement.bindString(2, records[1]);
                    statement.bindString(3, records[2]);
                    statement.execute();
           }
           sampleDB.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
           sampleDB.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Does this make it faster?

Comment: Really...its make data insertion faster..??

Comment: yes but read this link to get more information http://tech.vg.no/2011/04/04/speeding-up-sqlite-insert-operations/

Comment: Yes, it does make it faster.  Each transaction is an file open and close.  Doing that for each insert is extremely expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Don't open and close the database every time you want to do an insert. Open it once and then close it when exiting the app.

Comment: +1, You should also check this.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `Async`class. Do the operation `onBackground`, not in the main UI thread.

UPDATE

On your code, you insert the SQLite via `onPost`, not `onBackground`. `onPost` do things on UI thread, while `onBackground` do it on the separate (background) thread so it doesnt effect the UI. So **move** the operation code to `onBackground`.

Comment: Does that improve SQLite performance?

Comment: Yes..all the insertion is performed in Asynk Task..

Comment: @user3249477 yes, it makes the UI thread run like usually so user wont notice you are inserting the DB. Remember, we talk about thousand of rows here.

Comment: @user1690714 Please post the async code too, maybe we can find something there.

Comment: @BlazeTama you didn't answer my question. Only said that user won't notice, that doesn't mean that SQLite performance has improved.

Comment: @user3249477 Sorry i dont really get your point. I think he create this question because the insert operation make his apps lag. If not, why we care?

Comment: My point is the OP asked for a faster insert not an insert that is done in the background. `If not, why we care` ?

Comment: plz..give the proper answer guys..

Comment: I tried to help with what i knew. A downvote? Where is the love guys?